# Convert a latex command with parameter into a two begin end commands without parameter

Tags: macros, boxes, grouping

I have defined a command

```
\newcommand{\CV}[1]{\parbox[c]{0.2\textwidth}{\begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}}}
```

which I obviously have to call like

```
\CV{My text}
```

However I rather would like to use two separate commands **without** parameters (my reason is in endnote [*]), so that the call sequence looks like:

```
\beginCV My text \endCV
```

How can I define these commands, so that the `\parbox` gets appropriately "opened" and "closed".

---

[*] *I use `pandoc` to convert markdown documents to LaTeX or HTML, and I tweak the LaTeX output a bit with some helper commands. This  does not affect the HTML output, **as long as no text is a parameter to a LaTeX command**.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment form of `\parbox` is `minipage`:

```
\newenvironment{CV}
 {\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}\raggedright}
 {\end{minipage}}
```

Note that you *don't* want a `flushleft` environment inside the `minipage`, because it adds vertical space fore and aft; with `\raggedright` this doesn't happen.

Now you can call

```
\begin{CV}
Text
\end{CV}
```